# Can I trim values on COPY from csv?

Tags: postgresql, copy

I used [csvsql](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/scripts/csvsql.html) to generate CREATE statements, and it looks like it assumed trimmed fields though the data has some spaces padding the field:

```
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(11)
CONTEXT:  COPY example, line 1314, column state: " South Korea"
```

I'm not entirely sure why the data has padding -- it definitely shouldn't but about half the values in the state column have some padding around them.

I could use [`ALTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-altertable.html) to make more space in the field, and then `UPDATE example SET state=trim(state);` after I `COPY` the csv in, I'm wondering if there's a clean way to just trim the padding as I import the data?

Comment: Does adding `--skipinitialspace` help?  Also, I'd just pick the `CREATE` statements, adjust them to my needs (for example, one could remove the limit from `varchar` - see the tip under https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-character.html) and then just copy the data (not fully sure how it's done with `csvsql`).

Comment: `--skipinitialspace` doesn't help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the `--no-constraints` option to csvsql may solve that problem simply.

Otherwise `COPY` has a `PROGRAM` clause that can pre-process the data. It receives the lines it on its standard input and must output the filtered result on its standard output.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

> PROGRAM
>
> A command to execute. In COPY FROM, the input is read from standard output of the command, and in COPY TO, the output is written
>   to the standard input of the command.

When called from psql with `\copy tablename FROM PROGRAM ...` the program refers to a client-side command to launch by `psql`. When `COPY` is used, it's a server-side command run by the backend.

But the trimming itself is non-trivial. For instance, see [How to manipulate a CSV file with sed or awk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26941/how-to-manipulate-a-csv-file-with-sed-or-awk) and [Trim leading and trailing spaces from a string in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600982/trim-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-a-string-in-awk).